# Procedure to assign large values in verilog parameter

Tags: verilog

I need to declare an array of parameters with large integer value in verilog. For example,

```
parameter real PARAM [0:2]= '{6.2e11 , 1e10, 2.5e9};
```

If I run this in verilog synthesis tool, it shows different values. Is it because the values are greater than 32 bit? What is the procedure to assign large values to the parameter?

Thanks

Farhana

Answer (score 1):

Synthesis tools do not work with real numbers.